What ML model for regression given tabular AND image data?
I'd like to predict the power production of a windfarm given the wind speed, its direction and other variables related to the specific wind turbines. However, due to wake effects (wind speed decreases in the region downstream of turbines, so those produce less power), I'd like to include information on the layout of the farm in the form of an image (either 0-1 pixels for the presence/absence of a turbine, or the wind speed field over the farm).
I'm thinking about a CNN for the layout part, but since I won't have much data (<2000) a MLP for the tabular part seems like it'd overfit. Is there a way to combine a random forest/XGB and a CNN for regression ?

You can of course add the coordinates of the wind farms as two new columns and let the model figure it out.

@user2974951 The problem is that the windfarms may have different sizes, so the vector of coordinates might be of different sizes for each datum. Would that be a problem ?

I don't know, maybe. You could try adding the size as well, either as coordinates + size, or coordinates for one end to the next.

How many wind farms are included in your data? How far apart are they? What is the range of turbine counts these farms have? If the data collected is at the turbine level, we will have spatially clustered data. I think you may instead run a spatial-lag model where the power output of one turbine affects those around it.


Is there a way to combine a random tree/XGB and a CNN for regression ?

An MLP that is integrated into the main architecture would actively learn the best patterns to extract based on the regression task. There are techniques to mitigate overfitting if that becomes a problem. You can start by overfitting, and then titrate in some regularisation to help the net generalise better.
The MLP block would distil the tabular data down to vector shaped $(N_{features}^{MLP}, 1)$, and the CNN block would do a similar thing with the image data, giving $(N_{features}^{CNN}, 1)$. Then, could you concatenate those feature vectors and feed them into a final layer that outputs a scalar value.
Another possibility is to model the problem (or part of it) using a graphical neural network (GNN). A GNN sounds like it has the right sort of inductive bias to represent the structure of the data, and as a result might perform well with the the limited data.
You could treat each turbine as a node, where its features include windspeed and direction, and the graph edges are distances (they could also be directed, representing whether a node is "downstream" or not).
That said, since windspeed is a function of both turbine and non-turbine causes (i.e. it matters both at the turbines and between them), I think a 2D CNN would still be useful to include in some way as a feature extractor for windspeed data.
@user2974951 suggested turning it into an entirely tabular problem by adding the windspeed data as new columns for XGB (correct me if I've misunderstood). I think that's an interesting idea and worth trying, especially as a quick-and-easy baseline. We won't be able to use much of the windspeed data in that case, since we're just using points where there is a turbine. But the model might perform well nonetheless and serve a baseline for "these are the results when we only use data at the exact turbine locations".
